# Enum Syntax Error? Identifier Expected? C# .NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, enums

I have done many `Enum` declarations before in .NET framework, but why is this not working in .NET Core 2.0?

```
public enum SomeOtherName
{
    Add,
    Subtract,
    Multiply,
    Divide
}

public static IEnumerable<string> Calculate(int num1, int num2, SomeOtherName operator)
    {

    }
```

VisualStudio2017 flags this as an error `CS1001 Identifier expected` and `CS1003 Syntax error, ',' expected`

Likewise, if I try something like

```
var op = Operator.Add;
```

in the method, I get the same error. Why?

Comment: Are you paying attention to the specific tokens that Visual Studio is highlighting with the error?  `operator` is rendered with the red squiggly line underneath indicating it is the cause of the error.  It's also rendered in blue because it's a keyword.

Comment: @BACON. tbh, I did not even see the change in colour. Thanks.

Comment: You can use `@operator` instead of `operator` and it won't produce a syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `operator` is a reserved keyword in C#. Can you change the name of your parameter so something else, such as operation instead?

```
public enum Operator
{
    Add,
    Subtract,
    Multiply,
    Divide
}

public static IEnumerable<string> Calculate(int num1, int num2, Operator operation)
{

}
```

Comment: Note, if you are really determined to use a keyword as a variable/parameter name, you can prefix it with @ to escape it

Comment: I've changed it to SomeOtherName, and I still get the same errors.

Comment: Subtle yet important nit with this answer: "Operator is a reserved keyword in C#".  `Operator` is not a keyword, but `operator` is.